# How to stop sequence reset in odoo11?

Tags: sequence, reset, odoo-11

ir.sequence - sequence in odoo 11 gets **resets everyday** how to stop resetting of sequence ?
Example :

day1 the records are created like 
CODE0001
CODE0002

day2 when records are created:
CODE0001
CODE0002

Instead i want sequence to be continued like CODE0003 in day2

Answer (score 0):

Please uncheck the option 'use_date_range' from the sequence : settings --> Sequence and Identifiers --> Sequences